# Extracting certain data from data separated by tabs

Tags: shell, unix, sh

```
256-56-8411  Bob      3.61  junior     cs
471-44-7458  Tim      3.45  senior     ce
326-56-4286  Rajesh   2.97  freshman   te
548-66-1124  Eric     2.88  sophomore  ee
447-21-3599  John     2.51  junior     cs
911-41-1256  Rebecca  3.92  senior     cs
854-22-6372  Robin    2.45  freshman   te
```

This data is separated by tabs. I need to write a shell command that will only display students whose ID does not start with a "4".

Comment: I'm sure you do. Your question is about as non-specific as it can get, and on top of that you have shown no effort whatsoever. You should fix those things first, then come back and ask when you have an actual coding problem. We would be glad to help with that.

Comment: I would try it with sed.

Comment: Why use shell? Using a scripting language like php will make this _far_ easier and more transparent.

Comment: This would be a (very) short sed command...

Comment: Yes, I would say less than 10 chars. How long would a php script be?

Comment: `grep '^[^4]'`, beat that, sed! `sed -n '/^[^4]/p'`... ugh!

Comment: @BenjaminW. You're right! sed is very short but... grep is even shorter in this case.

Comment: `grep -v ^4 `, or maybe `alias g='grep -v' `, then `g ^4 `

Comment: `sed '/^4/d'` works just fine, as does `sed /^4/d`

Comment: Please include actual text instead of a .png in future questions.

Answer (score 0):

"ID does not start with 4" is the same as "line does not start with 4" in this case.

You could

1. Write a shell script to loop over your lines and display the ones that don't start with "4":

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   while read line; do
       if [[ $line != 4* ]]; then
           echo "$line"
       fi
   done < "$1"
   ```
2. Use a Perl one-liner that prints lines not starting with "4":

   ```
   perl -ne 'print if /^[^4]/' infile
   ```
3. Use an awk one-liner doing the same:

   ```
   awk '/^[^4]/' infile
   ```
4. Use a sed one-liner *not* printing lines that *do* start with "4":

   ```
   sed '/^4/d' infile
   ```
5. Grep for lines by excluding the ones starting with "4":

   ```
   grep -v '^4' infile
   ```